# How is this mystery function using (foldr), right associative if it takes out the elements from the list starting from the left?

Tags: haskell

```
mystery [1,2,3]
       = foldr snoc [] [1,2,3]
       = snoc 1 (foldr snoc [] [2,3])
       = snoc 1 (snoc 2 (foldr snoc [] [3]))
       = snoc 1 (snoc 2 (snoc 3 (foldr snoc [] [])))
       = snoc 1 (snoc 2 (snoc 3 ([])))
       = snoc 1 (snoc 2 ([3] ++ [2])
       = [3,2] ++ [1]
       = [3,2,1]
```

I don't get how it is being right associative here using foldr. Since it takes 1 out of the list first, isn't that starting to evaluate from the left side of the list slowly to the right?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Since it takes 1 out of the list first, isn't that starting to evaluate from the left side of the list slowly to the right? Thanks.

Indeed, it *is* evaluating from the left but `snoc` is defined as

```
snoc x y = y ++ [x]
```

hence in the next step `x` appears to move from the "left" (first argument of `snoc`) to the "right" (in the second argument of `++`).

So, we have

```
snoc 1 (snoc 2 (snoc 3 ([])))
= snoc 2 (snoc 3 ([])) ++ [1]
= (snoc 3 ([]) ++ [2]) ++ [1]
= (([] ++ [3]) ++ [2]) ++ [1]
= [3,2,1]
```

---

If we wanted to follow the evaluation strategy  more pedantically, we should write:

```
mystery [1,2,3]
= foldr snoc [] [1,2,3]
= snoc 1 (foldr snoc [] [2,3])
= foldr snoc [] [2,3] ++ [1]
= snoc 2 (foldr snoc [] [3]) ++ [1]
= (foldr snoc [] [3] ++ [2]) ++ [1]
= (snoc 3 (foldr snoc [] []) ++ [2]) ++ [1]
= ((foldr snoc [] [] ++ [3]) ++ [2]) ++ [1]
= (([] ++ [3]) ++ [2]) ++ [1]
= ... = [3,2,1]
```

Note how in each step we simplify as to the left as possible.

That being said, in Haskell the evaluation order is not so important: as long as you perform correct reductions (and terminate) you 'll always end up with the same result. Evaluation order only matters when evaluating performance (and termination).

Comment: so basically snoc gets evaluated first before foldr? Or is foldr and snoc being used at the same time where foldr is making snoc associating from right to left?

Comment: `foldr` always produces something like `f x1 ( f x2 (f x3 ...))` no matter what `f` is. `f x1` actually is evaluated first before the tail `(f x2  (f x3 ...))`. In your case `f=snoc`, but that does not change anything.